# i have a form with multi checkboxes and select option. i want to enable the select option if checkbox is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a form with multiple fields. Each field has a select option and checkboxes. I want to enable the select option when the checkbox is clicked. The problem is that when I click the checkbox all the disabled select option enables.

```js
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked") === true) {
        var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']";
        $(group).attr("checked", false);
        $(this).attr("checked", true);
    } else {
        $(this).is(":checked", false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[2][]" />
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[2][]" />
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[2][]" />
```

Comment: Using a snippet to get around the sites question validation rules is not going to encourage people to answer your question.  Fix your question with an appropriate runnable snippet (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Kindly fix your code with all the input feilds mentioned in your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your html looks like this:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />
    <select disabled="true">
        <option>foo</option>
        <option>bar</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />
    <select disabled="true">
        <option>foo</option>
        <option>bar</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />
    <select disabled="true">
        <option>foo</option>
        <option>bar</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The following code will enable the select grouped with the checkbox:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    var checkbox = $(this);
    if (checkbox.is(":checked") === true) {        
        checkbox.parent().find("select").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
          checkbox.parent().find("select").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Please note that there might be better ways to find the select field (like a corresponding id), but this should give you an idea on how to do it.